AWS codepipeline for Java Gradle application
I am trying to setup codepipeline in AWS for Java Gradle application. The application is building fine. But when the jar file to uploaded to Elastic Beanstalk, I get 502 bad gateway nginx error. When I pull the logs, this is what I see.
But when I compile locally on my laptop (Windows) and that jar when I upload manually to codepipeline, its working fine. Jar file created through codepipeline, is giving the error.
AWS codepipeline env: Amazon Linux, Ubuntu
Java 1.8
Gradle 4.4
buildspec.yaml
Error log:  un 16 03:13:42 web: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtUserDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userAccountRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userAccountRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#6e59db0f' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6e59db0f': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
Jun 16 03:13:42  web: 3 change sets check sum
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1348) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: ... 25 common frames omitted
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userAccountRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#6e59db0f' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6e59db0f': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: 3 change sets check sum
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:327) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:131) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1609) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1361) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: ... 38 common frames omitted
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6e59db0f': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:440) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1254) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: ... 51 common frames omitted
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
Jun 16 03:13:42   web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
I tried comparing jar file from codepipeline and from local, only difference is the file size. I tried using Amazon linux, Ubuntu and Windows image to build from codepipeline, but no luck. Also moved the jar file to base directory. Still the same error
post_build:
commands:
# move the jar (by wildcard, agnostic to its name) to top level app.jar
- mv build/libs/*.jar app.jar
artifacts:
files:
# publish the now top level app.jar as the artifact
- app.jar

Use [code block] format for logs, code, configuration and any multi line text information. Currently the question is unreadable.

Learn to use markdown.
